# Проверить что записано в span

Tags: javascript

Как проверить что записано в span?

```js
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
a.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;
concole.log(a);
```

```html
<a class="list_tab active">
  <span class="name">?</span>
</a>
```

Пытаюсь так

Answer (score 2):

```js
// во-первых забыл индех [0] у ClassName("active")

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0];
// во-вторых  ты строкой ниже находишь тот или иной элемент, но ни как его не объявляешь 
a.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;

// в-третьих ошибка в не conCole,  а conSole
// в-четвертых, у тебя "а" уже иницализирован и является ссылкой
console.log(a);

//надо или так

console.log(a.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML);
// или просто пока присвоить чему-то SPAN
var span = a.getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML;
// потом выводить в консоли

console.log(span);
```

```html
<a class="list_tab active">
  <span class="name">?</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста https://jsfiddle.net/zzsc3bm3/

```
const span = document.querySelector('.list_tab span'); // если надо то добавьте сюда active
console.log(span.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Если в list_tab  не один span?

Comment: querySelectorAll. Если вам нужен первый или последний, то смотрите псевдо классы https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes например first-child или last-child. Можно даже указать конкретный номер.